# Store JSON input

Tags: json, django, django-views

I'm somewhat new to Django and am trying to get Content Security Policy reporting running on my application and am running into some issues with parsing and storing the JSON violation output. I have all reports POSTing to /csp_reports/ and have built a new app called security_report and added the following to my urls.py:

```
url(r'^csp_report/$', 'security_report.views.secreport'),
```

My models look like this:

import os

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class security_report(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    received=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    csp_report=models.CharField()
    blocked_uri=models.CharField()
    column_number=models.CharField()
    document_uri=models.CharField()
    line_number = models.IntegerField()
    original_policy= models.CharField()
    referrer = models.CharField()
    status_code = models.IntegerField()
    violated_directive = models.CharField()
    source_file = models.CharField()
    script_sample = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "events"
```

And my views.py which is not complete and not working is below. I am stuck on how to actually grab each individual parameter and dump it into my database. Is json.loads the right way to do this? If so, how do I perform the save()? I am only testing the blocked_uri in the view for now to test it out. I just keep hitting my except: and getting "not saved"

```
from security_report.models import security_report
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
import json

@csrf_exempt
def secreport(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        json_data = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
        try:
            data = json_data['csp-report']

            blocked_uri = data['blocked-uri']
            document_uri = data['document-uri']
            referrer = data['referrer']
            script_sample = data['script-sample']
            violated_directive = data['violated-directive']
            source_file = data['source-file']

            b = security_report()
                b.blocked_uri = blocked_uri
                b.save()
                response = ("saved to database!")


        except:
            response = "not saved"

        return HttpResponse(response)

    else:
        return HttpResponse("not a post request")
```

Comment: This is a failure to debug. As you can see, "not saved" is not a helpful error message. You need to understand what the exception is.. in other words, what is breaking your code? either remove the except, or print or otherwise log the exception value: `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: Just remove the try/Except to see what kind of error is risen. Any of the keys might be missing from the data. Also, are you sure you are not getting syntax error because of your strange indention? lines after b = security_report() are with one step further indent.